# Trouble installing Caffe in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install [Caffe](https://github.com/rbgirshick/caffe-fast-rcnn) in `Ubuntu 18.04` but facing some problem. After installing dependencies mentioned below when I run the command

```
make all -j4
```

I get this [error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/njob5zq3p1ahnq1/error2.txt?dl=0)

**Dependencies Installed**

> CUDA 9.0
>
> CuDNN 7.4

```
$ sudo apt install python-opencv
$ sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libopencv-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
$ sudo apt-get install libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
$ sudo apt-get install the python-dev
```

[Makefile.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux8n6ds3fafxu1v/Makefile.config?dl=0)

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, I had to comment the following flag in `Makefile.config` file

```
#USE_CUDNN := 1
```